# Jquery based drop-down navigational menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am trying to create animated (barely) drop down menu's. The JS files are available if you look at the source of my page. I have it basically working.

**My question is**: when I hover over something from the main menu, and then go directly down to the submenu that pops up (down), if I then hover over something in that menu and leave it will stay.

http://lmiah.site11.com/slide%20down%20box%20menu%20new/mainTest.html

**To be less confusing I will give a direct example**:

If you hover over "Careers" then move straight down and over and hover over "Employee Testimonials" then move your mouse down off the menu completely, the menu still stays until you hover over "Careers" again.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** I am finding that it has something to do with the `a href="# class="subMenuFloat"` Whenever I hover over these links (they are the ones in the hidden drop downs) my dropdown div remains. I cannot find why this happens, but if I simply hover over the li, and miss the link, it exits properly.

Comment: I think you should add a mouseout event for the .dropdown class

Comment: I was looking into doing something like that but I found it strange when you moused over the dropdown div, and moused out- after it being stuck there- It would disapear after you moused over the "Careers" again.

Comment: It won't harm if you give this a try--> href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: you are not using any onclick funct so it doesn't matter ... sorry my bad

Comment: Yeah basically what I'm wondering is why hovering over the links, causes the drop down to stay... it's strange but I am looking for solutions just can't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**demo :** http://jsbin.com/welcome/13456

example without using the menu-plugin, this is just a proof of concept

```
$(function() {
    var flag = false;
    $('#mainMenu li.mainMenuItems').hover(function() {
        if (!flag)
            $(this).find('.submenu').slideDown(500);

    }, function() {
        if (!flag)
            $(this).find('.submenu').slideUp(500);
    });

    $('#mainMenu li.mainMenuItems .submenu').hover(function() {
        flag = true;
    }, function() {
        $(this).slideUp(500);
        flag = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I need, however the transition effect is neccessary, along with the divs changing backgrounds when I hover over them. (See "careers" when you hover over it.)

Comment: Like I mentioned in the other Answer I may just scrap this and start from scratch (This was not initially my code.) -.-

Comment: you can just include the easing plugin and use like .slideDown({ duration: 1000, easing : 'easeBounceOut' ...! if you know the problem is not the plugin itself, then it is the css that have something wrong; otherwise look at my example for the use of the flag pattern!

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I have a better understanding of it!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when using the hover function in jquery because you the selector being used is actually moving from one element to another.  Here is the way I did this, basically you set a div or li inside the li of your menu.  Example:

```
<ul class="menu-hover">
  <li class="menu one">Menu Option One
    <div> Here is the drop down menu</div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu two">Menu Option One
    <div> Here is the drop down menu</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the jquery would be

Basically this is saying when you hover over an li in the menu, hide all the div under that menu which would be all the menus in your dropdown then show the div that is under the li that is hovered.  You will need to make the li position relative and the div absolute.  So theoretically the div is contained under the li and therefore when you hover it will stay open.

```
$(".menu-hover li").hover(function(){ 

 //Hide each div on hover
  $(".menu div").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $("div", this).show();
});
```

Comment: `$(".menu div").hide();` is enough, no need to loop!

Comment: I tried something similar, With my code however- it still sticks after I go over the sub menu li.

Comment: Try adding an overflow: hidden property to your .submenu class.  Since your lis are floating the height of the submenu container is 0.  Overflow hidden will take care of this

Comment: Tried the overflow:hidden, still shows :/ I may just scrap this and start from scratch, It is frustrating -.-